# Cannot read undefiend of '.html'

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to create a new webserver using nodejs, got an error saying .html is undefined.

```
var mimeType = {
    "html" : "text/html",
    "jpeg" : "image/jpeg",
    "jpg" : "image/jpeg",
    "png" : "image/png",
    "js" : "text/javascript",
    "css" : "text/css"
};

http.createServer(function(req,res){
    var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    var fileName = path.join(process.cwd(),unescape(uri));
    console.log('Loading '+uri);

    var stats;

    try{
        stats = fs.lstatSync(fileName);
    }catch(e){
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-type':'text/plain'});
        res.write('404 Not found\n');
        res.end();
        return;
    }

    // check if file/directory
    if(stats.isFile){
//error happen here
        var mimeType = mimeType[path.extname(fileName)].split(".").reverse()[0];
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': mimeType});

        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    }
}).listen(3000);
```

I'm new to node, I have no idea how to debug. Need help and guidance.

Comment: The console will tell you on what line and what file your getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in these lines:

```
var mimeType = mimeType[path.extname(fileName)].split(".").reverse()[0];
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': mimeType});
```

There, you're declaring a `mimeType` variable in the scope of the `createServer` response handler function, basically making the `mimeType` at the top of your code inaccessible. So, `mimeType` is `undefined` when you try to get a property from it: `mimeType[path.extname(fileName)]`

Rename that variable, and it should work:

```
var contentType = mimeType[path.extname(fileName)].split(".").reverse()[0];
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': contentType });
```

Comment: same error on that line. but this time error is cannot call split of undefined

Comment: That means `mimeType[path.extname(fileName)]` does not exist. What is the value of `path.extname(fileName)`?